# Working with multiple instances of a form in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have invested some time in searching but could not achieve what I actually want. I am working on a client server application with multiple clients and single server. All the connected clients are listed in a listview with a session ID. I have a communication form between client & server, which should be separate for each client. Since the no. of clients is not constant, i decided to use array to determine the client like this:

```
Dim chatSession() As frmChat
chatSession(sessionID).Show()
```

But I am getting **null reference exception**. I tried using **"New"** but again it says **Array cannot be declared with "new"**

Comment: use a `List(of Form)` or `List(of frmChat)` and you wont have to struggle with arrays and you wont have to worry about the size or whether a given element contains a form instance.

Comment: Unless you know exactly the number of forms you are including in your array, you are better off using a List as stated by @Plutonix, that will give you the advantage of being able to add additional forms. right now you are declaring your array but you have not put any frmChat items into it(you need to New up each instance of the Form and add it to your Array up to its upper bounds).

Answer (score 1):

The way you are going, you have to instance the array (so far you just declared it), then instance forms to put in it.  Then you have to keep track of which slots have active forms. Then, if you run out of slots, you have to resize it and ugh...it is all so very 1980s.

A Dictionary will allow you to easily store forms and find them by a unique key.  User name might not be unique so find/create something which is.

```
Friend frmList As New Dictionary(Of String, frmChat)   ' size is handled for us
```

Add a form

```
Dim f As New frmChat
' do stuff to start it up, maybe a name to identify it
f.Name = UniqueSessionID
frmList.Add(UniqueSessionID, f)
```

As a bonus, there can never be a slot or element in the dictionary (or List) without a valid form (though sloppy code could later result in an invalid form ref).

Remove one:

```
Dim f as frmChar = frmList(UniqueSessionID)
frmList.Remove(UniqueSessionID)
f.Close
```

Use one:

```
Dim f as frmChar = frmList(UniqueSessionID)
f.BringToFront       ' or whatever
' or simply:
frmList(UniqueSessionID).SendToBack
```